# error when Importing ethclient and common libraries

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I'am writting a script to interrract with a smart contract:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

var myenv map[string]string

const envLoc = ".env"

func loadEnv() {
    var err error
    if myenv, err = godotenv.Read(envLoc); err != nil {
        log.Printf("could not load env from %s: %v", envLoc, err)
    }
}

func main() {
    loadEnv()

    ctx := context.Background()

    client, err := ethclient.Dial(os.Getenv("GATEWAY"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not connect to Ethereum gateway: %v\n", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    accountAddress := common.HexToAddress("786af135e476c3b6061482e90c6273b8ee78c159")
    balance, _ := client.BalanceAt(ctx, accountAddress, nil)
    fmt.Printf("Balance: %d\n", balance)
}
```

I get undefined ethclient and undefined common.
The  import used to work fine, I think I have used some command to dlet the libraries or I'm using import from another folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to import the correct packages. Here's a working example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func main() {
    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
    }

    ctx := context.Background()

    fmt.Println(os.Getenv("GATEWAY"))
    client, err := ethclient.Dial(os.Getenv("GATEWAY"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not connect to Ethereum gateway: %v\n", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    accountAddress := common.HexToAddress("786af135e476c3b6061482e90c6273b8ee78c159")
    balance, _ := client.BalanceAt(ctx, accountAddress, nil)
    fmt.Printf("Balance: %d\n", balance)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not importing packages your code is using.

1. Add `import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"`
2. I am not sure where `common` package should be, but you're missing import for it as well.